# Using a URI to access a SOAP webservice instead of IP

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, iis-6

I have a test web-service: https://r3reports.retain3d.com/API/Reporting.asmx

In my production i have the following structure:
- IIS Application for my main application
- IIS Application within the main application for my webservice

---

When running from Visual Studio, my app is able to talk to the webservice without issue (it is pointing at the url above, not a locally hosted version). BUT when it runs in production, the TEST call times out because it is trying to use the IP to get to the webservice instead of the URL name (which is what is configured in IIS for SSL purposes).

---

What am i doing wrong and how can i force the SOAP call to use the URL instead of the IP?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, turns out we had to modify the host file on the server to properly map the child app to the right IP (it was resolving to the external IP which wasn't bound to my application instance)